# How do I Encapsulate a Custom UIPicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, adapter, uipickerview

I have a custom UIPicker that I want to encapsulate so I can reuse it.
The only thing I want left exposed is a delegate protocol that will tell the ViewController using the Subclassed UIPicker what the scale has been changed to.

Here's what it should look like on the bottom and what it looks like on the top.

[image]

Here's the crash msg that logs when I move the top picker in the picture:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableViewRowData.m:1630
```

Here's my code for the encapsulated class. I haven't figured out the delegate protocol I'm going to write but I want to handle the UIPickerView dataSource and delegate protocols in the encapsulated class. That way all I have to do to reuse it is implement the custom delegate protocol that tells me what the scale has been changed to.

This code is what worked in the with the viewController as the dataSource and delegate of UIPickerView. I'm trying to learn how to make reusable objects.

```
#import "SWScalePickerView.h"
@interface SWScalePickerView()<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *fractions;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSDecimalNumber *integer;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSDecimalNumber *fraction;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSDecimalNumber *scale;

@end

@implementation SWScalePickerView

@synthesize fractions = fractions_;
@synthesize fraction = fraction_;
@synthesize integer = integer_;
@synthesize scale = scale_;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setDataSource:self];
        [self setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

#pragma mark - UIPicker

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return 10;
            break;
        case 1:
            return [fractions_ count];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row];
            break;
        case 1:
        {

            //return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row];
            return [fractions_ objectAtIndex:row];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return @"Fix Something";
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 55.0;
}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{


    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            integer_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row]];
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            NSString *string = [fractions_ objectAtIndex:row];
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"--"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1/8"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.125"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1/4"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.25"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1/3"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.33"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"3/8"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.375"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1/2"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.5"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"5/8"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.625"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"2/3"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.666"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"7/8"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.875"];
            }
        }
            break;
    }
    scale_ = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
    scale_ = [integer_ decimalNumberByAdding:fraction_];
    NSLog(@"%@",[scale_ stringValue]);

    //[scaleButton_ setTitle:[scale_ stringValue] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by, "look like on the bottom and what it looks like on the top". Do you have 2 different pickers? The code looks like it's only meant for the bottom one.

Comment: The code is for the top picker. The bottom picker uses the same code but it's scattered throughout a viewController

Comment: Hmmm... but you say the top one should look like your image? It looks like it has only one component, and it's full width, not 55 as you're returning in widthForComponent:. Also, how does fractions_ get populated? Are you passing in that array?

Comment: Solved that part. Will post the complete answer once I figure out the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. Because I'm using interface builder I had to to initialize the dataSource and delegate in the initWithCoder method and not initWithFrame. That solve the first error.

To get this custom picker to return the scale to the viewController that is using it you make the viewController conform to a protocol. Then in the didSelectRow delegate method in the custom class you call the method that the view controller with be implementing. It's called "dancePuppets" right now. That's a Fresh Prince of Bel Air joke. That's where you can return the scale.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SWScalePickerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)dancePuppets;    //Method that 

@end

@interface SWScalePickerView : UIPickerView
{
    IBOutlet id<SWScalePickerDelegate> client;
}

@end

#import "SWScalePickerView.h"
@interface SWScalePickerView()<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *fractions;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSDecimalNumber *integer;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSDecimalNumber *fraction;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSDecimalNumber *scale;

@end

@implementation SWScalePickerView

@synthesize fractions = fractions_;
@synthesize fraction = fraction_;
@synthesize integer = integer_;
@synthesize scale = scale_;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:decoder])) {
        [self setDataSource:self];
        [self setDelegate:self];
        fractions_ = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"--",@"1/8",@"1/4",@"1/3",@"3/8",@"1/2",@"5/8",@"2/3",@"7/8",nil];
        integer_ = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
        fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
        //[picker_ selectedRowInComponent:1]
        [self selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setDataSource:self];
        [self setDelegate:self];
        fractions_ = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"--",@"1/8",@"1/4",@"1/3",@"3/8",@"1/2",@"5/8",@"2/3",@"7/8",nil];
        integer_ = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
        fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
        //[picker_ selectedRowInComponent:1]
        [self selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

#pragma mark - UIPicker

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return 10;
            break;
        case 1:
            return [fractions_ count];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row];
            break;
        case 1:
        {

            //return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row];
            return [fractions_ objectAtIndex:row];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return @"Fix Something";
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 55.0;
}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{


    switch (component)
    {
        case 0:
            integer_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",row]];
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            NSString *string = [fractions_ objectAtIndex:row];
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"--"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1/8"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.125"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1/4"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.25"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1/3"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.33"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"3/8"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.375"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"1/2"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.5"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"5/8"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.625"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"2/3"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.666"];
            }
            if ([string isEqualToString:@"7/8"]) {
                fraction_ = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.875"];
            }
        }
            break;
    }
    scale_ = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
    scale_ = [integer_ decimalNumberByAdding:fraction_];
    NSLog(@"Set Scale to: %@",[scale_ stringValue]);

    [client dancePuppets];

    //[scaleButton_ setTitle:[scale_ stringValue] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return;
}


@end
```